# VS Code autocomplete Symfony doesn't work

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, visual-studio-code

I use vs code but I can't get autocomplete on a doctrine entity when I'm in a controller. For example:
$user->getNa... doesn't show getName().

I tried a lot of plugins but no one worked (PHP IntelliSense, PHP Intelephense, PHP Intellisense-Crane, PHP-Autocomplete, Symfony for VSCode, Symfony Snippets).

```
public function nameAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $EntitiyRepository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Entitiy');
    $user = $EntitiyRepository->find(5);
    $company = $user->getcomp
    return $this->render('index.html.twig');
}
```

Comment: which plugins have you tried? And how did they not work? Your question doesnt really give much useful info to try to help

Comment: @L01C, I suggest you to use `phpStorm` with plugins + `PHPAnnotations` + `Symfony plugin`

Comment: To be sure, you don't have an `exit;`before your code ?

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev phpStorm is very slow on my compute, even if I could because I have a licence.

Comment: @Alexis No exit at all ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You should probably type hint for VSCode to know which type gets returned by the find method.

```
public function nameAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $EntitiyRepository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Entitiy');
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $EntitiyRepository->find(5);
    $company = $user->getcomp
    return $this->render('index.html.twig');
}
```

Comment: It works if I add the "/** @var User $user */" but I don't want to need to add that plus a "use" statement(use me\UserBundle\Entity\User;)
 in each file everytime I need it.

Phpstorm does it without both so I guess there is a way to do it with vs code. 
No one use vs code with a Symfony project ?

Comment: Phpstorm has a 'Symfony' plug-in that takes care of this. Of course, there will be a way to do it with VScode but someone should write a plug-in for it... By default, your IDE does not know what kind of object the find method returns. FYI I use vs code with Symfony.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nadim-vscode.symfony-code-snippets) and add this code to your settings.json or .code-workspace file

```
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": true,
    "strings": true
  }
```